# Why is are the simplicial 1-chains $[A,B] \neq -[B,A]$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplex

This is a really simple question that I think I have answered, but I'm not altogether satisfied and would like confirmation or an alternative. We define the simplices

$$
\begin{align}
[A,B] : \Delta^1\to\mathbb R & & [B,A]:\Delta^1\to\mathbb R \\
e_1 \mapsto A & & e_1\mapsto B \\
e_2\mapsto B & & e_2 \mapsto A
\end{align}
$$

where $\Delta^1$ is the standard 1-simplex and $e_1 = (1,0), \, e_2 = (0,1)$. I'm now asked to prove that $[A,B] \neq -[B,A]$ in $S_1(\mathbb R)$, but they are in fact equal in homology. Oddly the second part is the easiest, since I have found a chain $\sigma$ such that $\partial\sigma = [A,B] + [B,A]$. I'm still getting used to the group of simplicial chains just being *declared* as it is (unlike homotopy groups which are more obviously tied to topological operations), which is my confusion with the first part. Am I correct in saying that $[A,B] \neq -[B,A]$ because, since $S_1(\mathbb R)$ is the *free* abelian group generated by all 1-simplices, then $\langle [A,B]\rangle \cap \langle [B,A]\rangle = 0$ (since they are not equal as maps) and therefore one cannot be a multiple of the other?

Comment: Note that $S_1(\Bbb R)$ is *free* generated by the singular simplices, so two simplices $\sigma,\tau$ are equal iff they are the *same* (and this sort of generalizes to sums, where we want the same simplices with the same integer coefficients). Thus, being different functions, $[A,B]$ and $[B,A]$ are not the same.

Comment: They are distinct, and this is for purely algebraic reasons: The free Abelian group is by definition the group of all finite sums $\sigma_1+\dots+\sigma_n$, up to the ordering of the summands, where $\sigma_i$ are (not necessarily different) singular simplices. So $[A,B]$ and $-[B,A]$ are distinct by definition.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This is the argument I had made, but I had trouble accepting it. I guess I shouldn't have.